# Retrieving volume of bodies in CATIAVBA

Tags: vba, catia

I am developing a macro in CATIAVBA to automatically detect standard components, we are looping through the bodies since they have been imported from a previous version of CATIA, and we have found that standard components follow a rule related to the volume but we are not able to find a way to retrieve the volume from the body directly. Is there a way to do this?

We tried exploring the properties available in bodies and solids but were unable to find anything so far. Any help will be appreciated.

NOTE: We found out it is possible to retrieve it from the product, but this is no use to us in our specific application.

Comment: please have a look onto the _measureable_ object of the SPA workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CATMain()

    For Each doc In CATIA.Documents
        If TypeOf doc Is PartDocument Then

            Set part = doc.part
            Set body = part.MainBody
            
            Dim spaWorkbench As Workbench
            Set spaWorkbench = doc.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench")

            Dim reference As reference
            Set reference = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(body)
                
            Dim measure As Measurable
            Set measure = spaWorkbench.GetMeasurable(reference)
            
            MsgBox measure.Volume
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```